# Can I request to server while my app is not opened at phone?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, push-notification, appdelegate

My program have to send to server request every 30 mins. Even when the phone is not launched. Than when  if program receives the json data from server it have to show the push notification to user. It is possible or not ? If yes I know how to write json request etc. please help with where can i do this and  how can I show the notification to user.  Thanks
P.S. I am coding in Swift 3

Comment: For Background Execution : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html  And For Push Notification https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @Азамат Булегенов : Simplest possible answer, NO you cant !

Answer (score 0):

I would say you want something like this [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)